# ExtJs adding items after viewport is created

Tags: javascript, extjs

I would like to check with you guys. Are these two blocks of codes doing the same thing?

```
me.viewport = new Ext.container.Viewport({
    items: [ me.mainPanel]
});
```

and

```
Ext.application({
    autoCreateViewport: true,
//then later ....
viewport = Ext.getCmp('viewport');
viewport.Add(me.mainPanel);
```

Except that one is created at the very beginning, other one is created on the spot. But they do the same job other than that, right? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do the same job. When passing it as a config option, ExtJs internally calls `initComponent`  and `initItems` that does the `add` as well.

Caution when adding multiple items. Don't call `add` multiple times because ExtJs will do an `updateLayout`. Instead pass multiple items as an array.

Hint: use `insert` to pass items between existing items (I am not sure but you might need to call updateLayout after this one)

Comment: Thanks for the confirm +1 for extra hints :D